# finding a cummulative distribution function from a uniform density function

Tags: probability-distributions

how can I find a cummulative distribution function from a piecewise uniform density function?

Answer (score 0):

Let the pdf be $P(x)= \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    a_1 & : l_1\leq x < l_2,\\
    a_2 & : l_2\leq x < l_3,\\
{}\,\vdots\\
    a_n & : l_{n}\leq x < l_{n+1},\\
  \end{array}
\right.
$

such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(l_{i+1}-l_i)=1$

Then the cdf will be:

$$F(x)=a_{n(x)}(x-l_{n(x)})+\sum_{i=1}^{n(x)-1} a_i(l_{i+1}-l_i),$$

where $\displaystyle n(x)=\max_{i,x>l_i}\  i$.